# Parse and change a file line-by-line while preserving EOL characters in Java

Tags: java, file-io

One hell of a long question :)

Here's how I usually do it:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(s));
while ((String line = r.readLine()) != null)
    b.append(doSomethingToTheString(s) + "\n");
```

However, this replaces all the new line characters in the file with a line feed, plus it adds one at the end if there wasn't one. What I want is to preserve EOL characters, even if it's mixed up like this:

```
Hello\r\n
World\n
This is\r
Messed up
```

What would be the most elegant/efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to keep the line terminators, use an `InputStream` instead of a `Reader`. You'll need to implement your own `readLine()` function that looks for a standard newline character/pair and leaves it in the return value.

If you are trying to output a file similar to the input that simply has the default line endings of the host OS, use a `Writer` or append the line terminator found using `System.getProperty("line.separator")`.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. This will change all EOLs to the system default without preservation.

Answer (score 4):

That's not a long question :)

Basically you won't be able to do anything with `BufferedReader.readLine()` here. It always removes the line terminator, and there's nothing you can do about that.

However, you could look at the code within `readLine()` (assuming the licence is compatible with whatever context you're writing code in) and basically perform the same task yourself, but preserving the line terminators.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch of a solution, since I don't have time to elaborate a complete code snippet.

1. You need a class (say, `WeirdLine`) to represent each line, basically with a String field for the line contents, and a byte[] field for the line terminator.

   `class WeirdLine {
    final String line;
    final byte[] term;
   }`
2. You need a class (say, `WeirdLineReader`) to wrap an `InputStream`.  It can expose a method `readWeirdLine()` which returns an instance of `WeirdLine` or `null` when the stream is empty
3. `WeirdLineReader` will need to maintain an internal byte buffer.  When `readWeirdLine()` is called, shovel bytes into the buffer (`InputStream.read()`), growing it as necessary, until

   a. `read()` returns -1, end of file.  `readWeirdLine()` returns an instance with a null terminator field, and the entire contents of the `String` you get from `new String(buffer[])`.

   b. A `findTerminator()` method scans to find the byte sequence \r\n or \n or whatever other terminators you want to cope with.  This method should also return a `WeirdLine` or null, and should leave the internal buffer cleaned out/truncated if so.

   c. The internal buffer is simply empty, return `null`

You then need to write a corresponding mechanism to write `WeirdLine`s back out, preserving the terminations.

This might be easiest to use `ByteBuffer` rather than a raw `byte[]` for the internal buffer.

Probably can adapt the code to [`BufferedReader`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/BufferedReader.java#BufferedReader.readLine%28boolean%29) if this sounds daunting.